# Как получить список игр, которыми владеет пользователь Steam

Tags: c++, steam

Как получить список игр, которыми владеет пользователь Steam  с помощью Steam API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно отправить `GET` запрос на адрес `http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=xxx&steamid=yyy&format=json`

Где

- `key` - ваш [SteamApi Key](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey)
- `steamid` - steamID64 нужного аккаунта
- `format` - необходимый формат данных, который вы получите (`json`/`xml`/`vdf`)

Также можно добавить дополнительные параметры:

- `include_appinfo` - в ответе будут также данные об игре (ее изображение и название) (по умолчанию только ID игры).
- `include_played_free_games` - выводит также и бесплатные игры, которые есть на аккаунте.
- `appids_filter` - вывод только определенные AppID.

При успешном запросе вам выдадут все необходимые данные в нужном вам формате, например JSON будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
{
  "response": {
    "game_count": 616,
    "games": [
      {
        "appid": 220,
        "playtime_forever": 133,
        "playtime_windows_forever": 0,
        "playtime_mac_forever": 0,
        "playtime_linux_forever": 0
      },
      {
        "appid": 340,
        "playtime_forever": 0,
        "playtime_windows_forever": 0,
        "playtime_mac_forever": 0,
        "playtime_linux_forever": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Здесь мы видим:

- `game_count` - сколько всего игр на аккаунте.
- `games` - массив со всеми играми.
- `appid` - id игры.
- `playtime_*` - сколько было сыграно в данную игру (всего/на определенной платформе).
- `не показанные данные` - имя, изображение и др. Зависит от запроса, тут думаю разберетесь.

---

Вся информация была взята с [официальной документации](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29).

Comment: Для получения Steam Key требуется сайт где он будет использоваться. А я пишу приложение на Qt.

Comment: @r1ddle-5 любой укажите и радуйтесь жизни, я например пишу localhost.

Comment: смотрите, я играл в team fortress 2 >600 часов (её ID 440), но в этом файле не могу найти информации об этой игре

Comment: @r1ddle-5 Почитайте внимательно то, что я написал, а конкретней про `include_played_free_games`...

Comment: Не забудьте закрыть вопрос, приняв ответ как верный (галка слева).

Comment: все, я понял как. Евгений, вы - гений!